# Trying to update the content of the #content div of a page by clicking a linked image in a jquery slideshow

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm really stumped on this one, although I am new to jquery.

I am trying to create a page where I have a slide show of products at the top and that by clicking on one of the products, the page would update the main #content div with a page from my server. I'm using the .load() function in order to get an ajax call to bring up the page. Additionally I'm using event.preventDefault() so that the click of the link doesn't change the page completely.

No clue what I'm doing wrong at this point. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Also I've looked for other plugins to do what I'm trying to do, but with no success.

What I've done so far:

Code was pasted into this jsfiddle because stackoverflow kept complaining that I didn't have it formatted right. There is also css for the carousel but that seems to be working fine. I can include it if needed

http://jsfiddle.net/WDXMU/1/

`<div id="wrap">`

`<div id="mycarousel" class="jcarousel-skin-tango">`

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="page1.html"><img src="img1.png"alt="" /></a></li>
  <li><a href="page2.html"><img src="img2.png"alt="" /></a></li>
  <li><a href="page3.html"><img src="img3.png"alt="" /></a></li>
  <li><a href="page4.html"><img src="img4.png"alt="" /></a></li>
  <li><a href="page5.html"><img src="img5.png"alt="" /></a></li>
</ul>
```

`<div class="jcarousel-scroll">`
`<form action="">`
`<a href="#" id="mycarousel-prev">&laquo; Prev</a>`
`<a href="#" id="mycarousel-next">Next &raquo;</a>`
`</form>`
`</div>`

`</div>`
`<div id="content">`
`Show the content`
`</div>`

`</div>`

The jquery code is in the fiddle because stack overflow didn't like it even with the escape character before and after

Answer (score 0):

I've made several changes to your jsfiddle, the first to set the framework to jQuery, which fixed the `a` tags navigating away from the page, I've removed the script tags from the javascript window, which cleared the junk at the beginning of the output, and I've fixed the missing # from the jQuery selector when you're trying to get the element with the id of `content`.

I've tested the code outside of jsfiddle and can confirm that it now works for me, but won't work in jsfiddle as the pages you've linked to don't exist on the jsfiddle domain.

http://jsfiddle.net/WDXMU/11/

Comment: The problem is that the page isnt loading into the div like it is supposed to.

Comment: For me it was navigating to the link, which it isn't now. I'll have another look.

Comment: OK, try again http://jsfiddle.net/WDXMU/11/. I fixed the missing # from #content, it still doesn't work, but isn't failing because it can't find the link (it's linking to http://fiddle.jshell.net/WDXMU/11/show/page1.html which doesn't exist)